# Give all values of h for which the matrix A fails to be invertible

Tags: matrices

Can someone please help me out with this please.  I know the answer is `h = 8` and I know the determinant is `21h - 168` and I even know the steps to find those answers.  For some reason this is giving me fits and I must be making silly mathematical mistakes that I keep missing.  First I have been simply using cofactor expansion and cannot come up with the correct answer. Then I used row reduction where I had a seven and two zeros in the first column.

I came up with `21h - 28` at one point and `119h + 28` at one point.

Thanks to anyone taking a look at this.  I know this is a pretty simple problem but I'm not getting something right.  I am studying for a test and fill like I am understanding everything pretty well, but this one problem is making me crazy!

First I use two row reductions.  R2 becomes `R1(-2)+R2` and R3 becomes `R1(-1)+R3`

So I get `{{7,-5,3},{0,3,-5},{0,-3,h-3}}`

[image]

Comment: If all you need to do is check your answer, just use [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+of+%7B%7B7%2C-5%2C3%7D%2C%7B14%2C-7%2C1%7D%2C%7B7%2C-8%2Ch%7D%7D).  It gives $21h-168$.

Comment: I don't just need to check my answer.  I already said I know the answer.  I am having problems getting the correct answer.

Comment: If you want people to find your mistake, you need to share your work.  Otherwise you will just get lots of computations of the correct answer.

Comment: In typing up my work, I found my mistake.  When I found the determinant of the 2x2 I have `7[(3h-9) + 15]` when it should be `- 15`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{det}\begin{bmatrix} 7 & -5 & 3 \\ 14 & -7 & 1 \\ 7 & -8 & h \end{bmatrix} 
&= 3\operatorname{det}\begin{bmatrix} 14 & -7 \\ 7 & -8 \end{bmatrix} - 1\operatorname{det}\begin{bmatrix} 7 & -5 \\ 7 & -8 \end{bmatrix} + h\operatorname{det}\begin{bmatrix} 7 & -5 \\ 14 & -7\end{bmatrix} \\
&= 3(14(-8) + 7(7)) - (7(-8) + 7(5)) + h(7(-7)+14(5))\end{align*}

From here, I suggest factoring $7$ out from every term. If you agree with what I have so far, then your problem is arithmetic, not linear algebra.

---

An easier way is to row-reduce to find $h$ such that the homogeneous system corresponding to the matrix has nontrivial kernel:
$$  \begin{bmatrix} 7 & -5 & 3 \\ 14 & -7 & 1 \\ 7 & -8 & h \end{bmatrix} \longrightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 7 & -5 & 3 \\ 0 & 3 & -5 \\ 0 & -3 & h-3 \end{bmatrix}\longrightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 7 & -5 & 3 \\ 0 & 3 & -5\\0 & 0 & h-8 \end{bmatrix}$$
The determinant is zero exactly when $h=8.$

Comment: I was using cofactor because that is what the instructions said but that is quick and easy to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

You may be forgetting to change the sign, depending on the row/column index sum:

If we expand along the first column, e.g., we have $$7 \left|\begin{matrix}-7&1\\-8&h\end{matrix} \right| - 14\left|\begin{matrix} -5 & 3 \\ -8 & h\end{matrix} \right| + 7\left|\begin{matrix} -5 & 3\\-7&1\end{matrix}\right|\tag{1}$$

$$ = 7 \Bigg(\left|\begin{matrix}-7&1\\-8&h\end{matrix} \right| - 2\left|\begin{matrix} -5 & 3 \\ -8 & h\end{matrix} \right| + \left|\begin{matrix} -5 & 3\\-7&1\end{matrix}\right|\Bigg)\tag{2}$$

$$\det A = 7\Big( (-7h+8) -2(-5h+24)+ (-5+21)\Big) = 7(3h -24) = 21(h - 8). $$

Hence, the determinant is zero if and only if $\;(h - 8) = 0 \iff  h = 8$. That means that the given matrix is invertible for all values of $h$ except at $h = 8$.

There are a lot of places where arithmetic errors can creep in, especially in keeping straight the signs.

Also notice the subtraction of the middle cofactor in $(1)$: since the entry $14$ has an index sum of $2+ 1=3$, it is odd, so that term needs to be subtracted.

Answer (score 0):

For three by three I typically use the the [rule of Sarrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus).

You get for the determinant
$$7(-7)h + (-5)1\ 7 + 3 \ 14 \ (-8) -( 7 (-7) 3 + (-8)1 \ 7 + h14\ (-5)).$$
So 
$$-49h -35 - 336 -( -147  - 56- 70h) = 21h -168. $$

Comment: We have not been over that in class.  I need to see the correct way to do it using cofactor expansion.

Comment: Ok. Sorry in fact I had even an error in writing it down. At least this is corrected.